# Load a template page via GET request with data from the previous page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, templates

I want to load a new template page with data inserted via the previous call.

I have a list of items generated and they link to the general item page but without php all is lost.

I was thinking about using a href="page.html#itemid" then finding the item by querying the url.

Is this overthinking it? Any easier ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that on the current page, you have used AJAX to load all the data you need to display on the new template page, correct?

I can think of multiple ways to do this. It just depends on the nature of your data:

1. Have a popup instead:
   You could have the new template page be a popup (instead of a real, separate page). Grey out the main page's content (via a darker, half transparent overlay) and then have this new popup div display the data you want. This is typically used on sites that want you to sign up for their newsletter, etc.
2. Pass the data via URL:
   If you have very small amounts of data and it isn't sensitive data, you can just pass it through the parameters. Let's say page.html is the new page template you want to populate the data with. Then just have the link on the current page be `page.html?itemid=123&param2=Hi` or something like that. Then, on page.html, make sure you have JS to read the parameters from the URL and display the data.
3. Pass the data via cookie:
   Otherwise, you might just want to use JS cookies. Especially if you have a medium or larger amount of data. Store the data loaded from AJAX into cookies. If you are expecting the user to open multiple page.html templates at the same time, you might want to use an identifier and pass it to each one, such as `page.html?itemid=1` and `page.html?itemid=2` etc. Then have that page.html's JS look up the appropriate cookie based on the URL's parameter id.

Do be careful and use best practices if handling sensitive data.

Comment: Cookies ! Thanks forgot that would be way easier